# How to allow only one feature/polygon to be edited at a time with Leaflet?

Tags: draw, edit, polygon, leaflet

It's been days I'm trying to solve my problem.

I have a polygon layer from a GeoJSON. I want to edit my polygons with the click event. When I click on a polygon it becomes editable but what I want is that when I click on another polygon, the first polygon is no longer in editable mode.

OpenLayers but naturally does not Leaflet.

Here's an excerpt from my code:

```
var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);
var polygon_json;
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "get_json.php", 
    success: function (response) {
                        meaux_json = L.geoJson(response, {
                        onEachFeature: onEachFeature    
                        });
                      }
    });

//edit the targeted polygon
function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
                    editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
                    layer.on('click', function(e){
                    e.target.editing.enable();
                    });
               }
```

One person was able to do it but I am having difficulty understanding how :
https://github.com/dwilhelm89/Ethermap

Comment: When I click on a polygon/polyline in your demo, it becomes editable. Then when I click another poly in your demo, editing on the first is disabled, and the 2nd polygon is enabled for editing. It seems like it is working how you want right now.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it's not my demo, it's another person who did that not me ^^, and i don't know how.

Comment: Hey. Can you please post your whole code (including the leaflet draw controls?) I try to do something similar but I am stucked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are close. In your onEachFeature function you should store the feature that was clicked so you can enable/disable editing in the click handler.

```
var selectedFeature = null;
//edit the targeted polygon
function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
     editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
     layer.on('click', function(e){
          if(selectedFeature)
               selectedFeature.editing.disable();
          selectedFeature = e.target;
          e.target.editing.enable();
     });
}
```