# Making polygons editable using leaflet-draw

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

How can I make polygons loaded on a map from a  database editable?

As of now, when the polygons get loaded they remain un-editable. The edit option only gets enabled when I create a new polygon.

> Polygons loaded from the database are marked blue and the newly
>   created  polygon is marked red. (The edit icons are screwed up!)

[image]

Comment: I found the following links helpful -http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203540/how-to-edit-an-existing-layer-using-leaflet  &  https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4461

Comment: Can you please post some code showing how you are converting database items to leaflet items? Here's my answer from a few years ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/26965160/859686

Comment: I had posted another question on stackoverflow. The answer to that question solved this issue as well. Here's the link --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376176/add-existing-leaflet-polygons-to-an-existing-leaflet-layer?noredirect=1#comment68009098_40376176

Answer (score 0):

```
let map = L.map("map").setView([41.31, 69.27], 12);
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);

let drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);
```

> // toolbar

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  draw: {. . .},
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems,
    poly: {
      allowIntersection: false
    }
  }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

map.on("draw:edited", function(e) {
  let layers = e.layers;
  layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    console.log(layer);
  });
});
```