# Add existing leaflet polygons to an existing leaflet layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have a bunch of polygons which are stored in a database. I would like to add them to the map in such a way that they can be edited using the [leaflet-draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) toolbar. Although, now the polygons get added to the map, I am unable edit them.

I think this is because they are not added to the [`layerGroup()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) to which newly drawn shapes are added.

Please help.

Comment: Did it solved your problem ?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to add your polygons to the featureGroup `drawnItems` ! Let's say,

```
    var polyLayers = dbArray;
```

is your database array with polygons. First create a feature group with your drawn items:

```
    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
```

and add it to the map:

```
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);
```

Then you simply need to iterate over your polygons from your database and add them to the drawnItems `FeatureGroup`:

```
    for(layer of polyLayers) {
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer); 
    };
```

Now the layers are added to the map and editable.

Here goes an [**EXAMPLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8przLuwa/):

```
    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);

    var polyLayers = [];

    var polygon1 = L.polygon([
        [51.509, -0.08],
        [51.503, -0.06],
        [51.51, -0.047]
    ]);
    polyLayers.push(polygon1)

    var polygon2 = L.polygon([
        [51.512642, -0.099993],
        [51.520387, -0.087633],
        [51.509116, -0.082483]
    ]);
    polyLayers.push(polygon2)

    // Add the layers to the drawnItems feature group 
    for(let layer of polyLayers) {
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer); 
    }
```

Comment: Adding on to this question. I would like to save shapes that have been edited by the user into the DB. Should I just do a brute force search comparing latlngs with their previous values in the "draw:edited" event or is there a better method?

Comment: Don't do it on draw edited, instead `draw:edited` enable or show a save button, then when save is clicked perform your save logic. I don't bother comparing I force overwrite, but for complex maps you wouldn't want to do it on every change. I guess you could also use a debounce routine... but for some users and changes the save to the database will take longer than their next edit to the shape.

Answer (score 0):

As a simplistic and straight forward approach you could also add the polygons to the map without using the FeatureGroup.

```
const polygon = L.polygon([[lat,lng],[lat,lng],[lat,lng]], { fillOpacity: 0.5, fillColor: '#9a8fcd' });
polygon.addTo(map);
```

You can of course loop through your data and add all the polygons in this way as well.